How can I limit the number of created connection when I connect to Solace using qpid JMS library in an Apache Beam application?
My Apache Beam application sends messages to a Solace queue. To send the message, I use the Apache Qpid JMS library and Java Messaging Service (JMS). However, when I launch my application, more than 2000 connections are created for two nodes. I have more than 2000 logs messages like the following when I start my Beam application:
Connection ID:0030887-f9c8-429f-b5d1-eda15330e262:1 connected to server: amqps://my.queue.address:54321

It bothers me as my number of connection to Solace is limited (400 connections)
Is there a way to reduce the number of JMS connections created in Apache Beam applications?
My code
I call the the writer in the following method:
@NotNull
@Override
public POutput expand(@NotNull PCollection<String> input) {
  input.apply(
      "WriteMessageToMyTopic",
      JmsIOWriter.writeMessage());

  return PDone.in(input.getPipeline());
}

JMS Writer
Here is the code of the writer
package com.example;

import com.example.StaticConnectionFactory;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jms.JmsIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jms.RetryConfiguration;

final class JmsIOWriter implements Serializable {

  public static JmsIO.Write<String> writeMessage() {
    var connectionFactory = StaticConnectionFactory.getFactory();

    return JmsIO.<String>write()
        .withRetryConfiguration(RetryConfiguration.create(5))
        .withConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
        .withTopicNameMapper(m -> topicMapper(m, "my/topic/"))
        .withValueMapper(JmsIOWriter::valueMapper);
  }

  private static Message valueMapper(String element, Session session) {
    try {
      return session.createTextMessage(element);
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          String.format("Unable to send message in queue %s", element), ex);
    }
  }

  private static String topicMapper(String message) {
    return "my/topic/" + message.length;
  }
}

Connection Factory
I use a static connection factory that I inject in the writer
package com.example;

import org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;

public final class StaticConnectionFactory {

  private static JmsConnectionFactory factory;

  public static synchronized JmsConnectionFactory getFactory() {
    if (factory == null) {
      factory = new SslJmsConnectionFactory();
      factory.setUsername("myUsername");
      factory.setPassword("myPassword");
      factory.setRemoteURI("amqps://my.queue.address:54321");
      factory.setForceAsyncAcks(true);
      factory.setReceiveLocalOnly(true);
      factory.setReceiveNoWaitLocalOnly(true);
    }
    return factory;
  }
}

SSL connection factory
This static connection factory returns an SSL connection factory
package com.example;

import static com.example.SslContextFactory.createSslContext;

import java.util.Base64;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;

public class SslJmsConnectionFactory extends org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory {

  @Override
  public Connection createConnection(String username, String password) throws JMSException {
    initSslContext();
    return super.createConnection(username, password);
  }

  private void initSslContext() {
    setSslContext(
        createSslContext(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(this.getUsername()), this.getPassword().toCharArray()));
  }
}

SSL context factory
This SSL connection factory use SSL context factory to initialize SSL context
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

public final class SslContextFactory {

  public static SSLContext createSslContext(byte[] credentials, char[] password) {

    try (var inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(credentials)) {
      var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      keyStore.load(inputStream, password);
      return initSslContext(keyStore, password);
    } catch (IOException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create SSL context", e);
    }
  }

  private static SSLContext initSslContext(KeyStore keyStore, char[] password) {
    try {
      var sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
      var keyManagerFactory = createKeyManagerFactory(keyStore, password);
      sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
      return sslContext;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize SSL context", e);
    }
  }

  private static KeyManagerFactory createKeyManagerFactory(KeyStore keyStore, char[] password) {
    try {
      var keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
      keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
      return keyManagerFactory;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize a key manager factory", e);
    }
  }
}

What I tried so far

Use static JMS connection factory to avoid recreating connections, no effect
Setup SSL context when initializing JMS connection factory instead of initializing it when I create a connection. I was unable to connect to the queue due to org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.exceptions.ProviderConnectionSecuritySaslException: Client failed to authenticate using SASL: PLAIN
I currently cannot use new Solace Writer available since Apache Beam 2.61.0 as it is labeled as experimental


Have you considered using a connection pool?

it certainly looks as if every time you try to JmsIOWriter.writeMessage() it recreates a new connection. You don't seem to be using Spring but I'll link this since it seems related.

https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-amqp-0-x-6.4.0/jms-amqp-0-8-book/JMS-Client-0-8-Appendix-PooledConnecytionFactory.html This might be useful
